# Laravel table migrate error with Foreign key

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-artisan

) I have a problem with migrate table to database. It's orginal wersion table (worked):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('revisions', function ($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('revisionable_type');
        $table->integer('revisionable_id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('key');
        $table->text('old_value')->nullable();
        $table->text('new_value')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->index(array('revisionable_id', 'revisionable_type'));
    });
}
```

I redo this table on:

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('revisions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('revisionable_type');
        $table->integer('revisionable_id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('key');
        $table->text('old_value')->nullable();
        $table->text('new_value')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();           
    });
     Schema::table('revisions', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

I can't add this table beacause artisan returned error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1005 Can't create table `kurwa_magazyn`.`#s   ql-1a68_a98`
>   (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (S   QL:
>   alter table `revisions` add constraint `revisions_user_id_foreign`
>   fore   ign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
>   table `kurwa_magazyn`.`#s   ql-1a68_a98` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
>   constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: You have `user` table already created ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH No I don't have thanks;) now worked ;)